# How to enable debug into estudio

Tags: eiffel, eiffel-studio-20.05

I tried to enable the debug syntax into estudio without afording it. In this case it is from a library and it doesnt enter into the

```
debug
     io.put_string ("any debug statement here")
end
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debug statements can be enabled and disabled by the associated key. Provided that there is no key in the example, the statement can be turned on by setting the value for *Unnamed Debugs* to `True`.

**Edit.** Named debug statements look like

```
debug ("foo")
    ...
end

debug ("foo", "bar")
    ...
end
```

where `foo` and `bar` are debug keys that are used to select which statements to enable. Here, if `foo` is selected, both statements are enabled at run-time. If `bar` is selected, only the second statement is enabled.

Comment: thx, what would be an example of key? syntax?

Comment: @Pipo I've added an example.